# React Router v4 Redirect Passing State from Search to Results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Have a Search component that when a payload comes back redirects to a Results component. Would like for that Results component to show the passed State of Search using [React Router v4 Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect). My assumption here from the Docs is that using `state: { referrer: currentLocation }` an object can be passed.

**Search**

```
export default class Search extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        searchValue: '',
        results:[]
      }
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
  }

  handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    let searchParam = e.target.value;
    if (e.key === 'Enter'){
      axios
        .get(URL+searchParam)
        .then((response) => {
          this.setState({results: response.data});
        });
    }
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input
          ref="search"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress.bind(this)}
        />
        {this.state.results.length > 0 &&
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/results',
            state: { results: this.state.results }
          }} />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
export default class Results extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results:[] // <<<<<< Not sure if this needs set
    }
  } 
  render(){
    console.log('SEARCH RESULTS STATE', this.state); // <<<< this either returns undefined or just an empty array depending if initial state is set
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Search Results</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Unless I'm not reading into this correctly, the problem seems to be that when the Redirect happens there isn't anything being passed into the Results component.

If value is entered and is successful Redirect happens Search State returns `Object {searchValue: "", results: Array(1)}` However Search Results state returns `Object {results: Array(0)}` or `undefined` depending on initial state setting.

Have also tried different component lifecycles on Results but unable to get any passed data that way. My thought there was maybe `componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps, nextState){}` might be able to get some passed data and could have state set via those means.

Answer (score 15):

at the beginning of the render() method from your main Class Component you have to code for example:

```
if (isLoggedIn){
    return <Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/anyPath',
      state: { stateName: this.state.anyState}
    }} />;
}
```

and in the component associated to the Route `/anyPath` you have to extract the passed state calling `this.props.location.state.stateName`. in your in your precise case you should call `this.props.location.state.results` in the Results Class. You can delete the constructor method from your `Results` class.

`isLoggedIn` could be another state, that you could set to false at first in the constructor Method from your main component. Then `isLoggedIn` could be set to true if your user clicks a button, and so you will redirect your app to another Route with preferred states.

Comment: How can you do this programmatically, like using `useHistory`?

Comment: if we use the state in redirect? then where  are we going to extract it to use in a component?and how should we use it?

Comment: RohanDevaki and @Buts sorry but I answered this question more than 3 years ago. Please refer the docs for more info about it.

Answer (score -3):

Looks like the object was getting passed, however it was nested in `location.state` and didn't look deep enough.

Comment: can you elaborate a little on the solution you found, please.

Comment: It has been awhile since looking at this and I don't have access to the codebase or application anymore. I think to make things more clear is that what I was looking for was in `location.state` but I wasn't looking deep enough in that object for what I needed.